# A definite integration problem

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\cos^2x}{1+a^x}dx$$
where $a>0$

This question is from my textbook. I am finding this question quite difficult to solve.

Comment: Take advantage of a symmetry.

Comment: Use $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} [f(x)+f(-x)] dx$

Comment: @ZAhmed Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Note that we have

$$\int_{-\pi}^0 \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x}\,dx=\int_0^\pi \frac{a^x\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x}\,dx$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how that symmetry would occur?

Comment: Thank you, I just understood that symmetry.

Comment: Pleased to hear.